# Custom content for several Spanish speaking countries

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am on Drupal 7.

I need a website that will have different versions for each country in Latin America, where many countries speak Spanish. I was considering using one language per country, but as far as I am concerned, Drupal has only one Spanish version. At least, it doesn`t have one Spanish for Costa Rica, another to Honduras, Panama, El Salvador, Colombia and so forth. So I was considering creating one flavor of Spanish per country in Drupal (I would create new custom languages like "es-country code") and loading all the Spanish vocabulary again and again into these alternative custom languages. Do you think this approach works? I would like to take advantage from the fact that when using localization (i18n) you can set one single structure/navigation for the website accross the languages. The content across different countries will usually be the same, but sometimes it will be different. Working with i18n I can duplicate content accross the countries and change the small details wherever I need.

So my question isn`t technical, but broader. Do you think this approach is good? Which strategy/approach would you use if you needed to content customization per country where some of these countries speak the same language? Thank you

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  For those unaware about about the nuances, when you do a "language" translation of a project, you often have a translation per region as local differences can be specific.  For example, Spanish usage can vary between Latin America and Europe as well as within Latin American.  Portuguese varies, too, between Portugal and Brazil.  On the other hand, forcing a language based on location isn't always the best idea (eg, expatriates may want to read a website in their native language and not primary language of where they live).

Comment: MPD, thank you for your comment. Since Portuguese is divided into Portuguese from Brazil and Portuguese from Portugal, it is kind of weird to see Spanish as an unified language with so many different flavors of it accross Latin America. But because there are so many, and creating one project for each would make Spanish a scattered language in Drupal (and a nightmare to maintain), they have probably decided to unify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the best solution, or at least we used the same. In Switzerland, we have the Swiss German, that is a little bit different from German.

So we took the German translation as a base and created another language, like de-ch. Then with i18n and all other modules, we translated the differences.